# How do I change the position of a point on a circle so that it goes from point to point?

Tags: c++, math

Imagine a dotted circle made of 100 points. Each verticle set of points are connected in a line. What I'm trying to accomplish is making an optical illusion by shifting the lines at the top move forwards and the ones on the bottom move backward. This creates an hourglass shape at the end. What I'm confused about is the math for it.

```
if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)){
                for(int a = 0; a <= 100; a++){
                    x1 = x1 + (a * 2 * pi / 100);
                    y1 = y1 + (a * 2 * pi / 100);
                    x2 = x2 - (a * 2 * pi / 100);
                    y2 = y2 - (a * 2 * pi / 100);
                    if(a % 2 == 0){
                        lines[a].position = Vector2f(x1, y1);
                        lines[a + 1].position = Vector2f(x2, y2);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm pretty sure this should work since I'm just adding the angle over and over again, but I'm suspicious about "a".

Comment: So what is the question? Does the code work, and if not, what are you asking?

Comment: I don’t get how the circle comes to play. There’s nothing here to make a circle, just points moving further and further away from each other with the same angle. Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: My question is, what math do I need to shift the lines so that the top goes forward, and the bottom goes backward.

Comment: I don't see how it would create all hour glass shape but shifting a set of lines to the right it should just be `pos.x += someConstantForEachLine`. Why are you ever modifying the y component of any vector? Either your description or code are way out.

Comment: What do terms `forward` and `backward` mean for 2D image?